# Misalignment of badges/numbers on user-profile page

Tags: bug, design, profile-page

The current user-profile page on [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com) shows the badges/numbers looking like this:

[image]

A similar mis-alignment exist in the post flair. Here is a similar view of the top-bar:

[image]

The vertical alignment of the badges in the user-profile/signature view should match that of the top-bar.

Tested on:

- Chrome 40.0.2214.111 m
- Firefox 35.0.1
- Internet Explorer 11.0.9600.17631

[Reproduceable](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3036812#3036812) on [Ask.Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Originally asked on [tex.se]: [Misalignment of badges/numbers on user-profile page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/5839/5764), but it seems wider-spread than that.

Comment: Most sites look fine repro here: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/
http://money.stackexchange.com/
http://mathoverflow.net/
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/
http://judaism.stackexchange.com/
http://apple.stackexchange.com/  (Chrome Version 40.0.2214.111 m)

Comment: It's a bug with the design of profile page, that's it. Flair and badges are not really relevant.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: You do notice the difference in the flair as well though, right? I'm not sure about the inner workings of the display, and whether the flair is related to the user-profile in terms of their display mechanisms.

Comment: [This is flair](http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/514155.png), so still not relevant. If you mean the top bar, it has its own tag. :)